# .vim/syntax/sql.vim: Error detected while processing BufRead Autocommands for "*.sql"

Tags: vim

I tried saving [this](https://github.com/JessicaKMcIntosh/Vim/blob/master/syntax/sql.vim) vim syntax file for sql but when I open a sql file in vim I get lots and lots of stuff like this:

```
Error detected while processing BufRead Autocommands for "*.sql"..function dist#ft#SQL[4]..FileType
Autocommands for "*"..Syntax Autocommands for "*"..function <SNR>4_SynSet[25]..script /home/bernie/.
vim/syntax/sql.vim:
line   17:
E117: Unknown function: vim_highlight#core#options#getValue
line   18:
E117: Unknown function: vim_highlight#core#options#getValue
line   22:
E121: Undefined variable: s:case_sensitive
line   29:
E121: Undefined variable: g:vim_highlight#core#options#default#common
E116: Invalid arguments for function extend
line   30:
E121: Undefined variable: g:vim_highlight#core#options#default#region
E116: Invalid arguments for function extend
line   35:
E117: Unknown function: vim_highlight#core#syntax#match
Error detected while processing BufRead Autocommands for "*.sql"..function dist#ft#SQL[4]..FileType
Autocommands for "*"..Syntax Autocommands for "*"..function <SNR>4_SynSet[25]..script /home/bernie/.
vim/syntax/sql.vim[156]..function <SNR>29_SelectStmt:
line    1:
E117: Unknown function: vim_highlight#core#syntax#predicat
line    2:
E121: Undefined variable: l:predicat
line    5:
```

etc etc

```
Here's the first part of the linked syntax file

" Vim syntax file for SQL
" Language:     SQL standard / Support for drivers specifics
" Maintainer:   Julien Rosset <jul.rosset@gmail.com>
"
" URL:          https://github.com/vim-highlight/sql/
" Version:      0.0.1

" For version 5.x: Clear all syntax items
" For version 6.x: Quit when a syntax file was already loaded
if version < 600
  syntax clear
elseif exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif

" Initialize options {{{
let s:driver         = vim_highlight#core#options#getValue('driver'        , '')
let s:case_sensitive = vim_highlight#core#options#getValue('case_sensitive',  0)
" }}}

" Case matching {{{
if s:case_sensitive
    syntax case match
else
    syntax case ignore
endif
" }}}

call extend(g:vim_highlight#core#options#default#common, { 'skipempty': 1, 'skipnl': 1, 'skipwhite': 1, 'contained': 1 })
call extend(g:vim_highlight#core#options#default#region, { 'keepend': 1 })

let s:predicats = { 'root': 'sql' }
```

Since this is someone's publicly released syntax file, to see so many errors makes me think there must be some broader problem with my vim setup. I'm using version 8.2.1847.

What do I need to make the attached vim syntax file work?

Comment: The linked [`sql.vim`](https://github.com/JessicaKMcIntosh/Vim/blob/master/syntax/sql.vim) is very different from what you quoted. It starts with "**Maintainer:   Jessica K McIntosh**" and doesn't have any mention of `vim_highlight`. OTOH the repository at https://github.com/vim-highlight/sql/ has the directory `autoload`. You just mixed up two different syntax files.

Answer (score 1):

--- EDIT ---

First, as mentioned in the comments, the file you linked to:

```
https://github.com/JessicaKMcIntosh/Vim/blob/master/syntax/sql.vim
```

is not the one in your question's body. The header of the pasted file:

```
" Vim syntax file for SQL
" Language:     SQL standard / Support for drivers specifics
" Maintainer:   Julien Rosset <jul.rosset@gmail.com>
"
" URL:          https://github.com/vim-highlight/sql/
" Version:      0.0.1
```

and the header of the linked file:

```
" Vim syntax file
" Language:     SQL with SQLite and other additions.
" Maintainer:   Jessica K McIntosh AT gmail DOT com
" Last Changed: Thu Jan 23 06:00 PM 2014 EST
```

are definitely different.

Second, it is quite easy to see that the errors in your question come from the file you pasted and not from the linked one. I mean, the following error:

```
line   17:
E117: Unknown function: vim_highlight#core#options#getValue
```

clearly poins to:

```
" pasted file
let s:driver         = vim_highlight#core#options#getValue('driver'        , '')
```

and not to:

```
" linked file
endif
```

right?

Therefore, the linked file and its parent repository are 100% irrelevant to the problem at hand, which is that…

--- END EDIT ---

That file is not standalone. It is not some random file taken from someone's config. It belongs to a complete plugin and depends on several other files under `autoload/vim_highlight/core` so you must install *the whole thing* for it to work correctly.

Use your favorite runtimepath/plugin manager for that, or use the native `:help packages` feature:

```
~/.vim/pack/<name>/start/sql
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see how to interpret your answer given the repository I linked. Its README and structure doesn't seem relevant (e.g. there is no `autoload` in the repository). How can you tell what plugin is required for this syntax file? (I don't want the tcl etc stuff in the full repository)

Comment: The linked file and its repo are irrelevant. See my edit.